# matplotlib contourplot for $\log z$ in the Complex Plane $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: finite-difference, numerical-analysis, numpy, mesh-generation

I tried using Python's matplotlib on the logarithm and here is what I got, a kind of starburst pattern.  Since the angle jumps between $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$, contour assumes there is a contour line between those those two points.  Here in in fact $\bbox[#EEEDAA,1pt]{0=2\pi}$

Perhaps instead of `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` the contour lines can be connected with `meshgrid` and `numpy.where` statements.

### Contour Plot of $\log z$ on $z \in [-1,1] + i[-1,1]$

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=4,4

plt.contour(
    np.arange(-1,1,0.01),
    np.arange(-1,1,0.01), 
    np.angle(t[...,None] + 1j*t[None,...]) , 
    levels = 2*np.pi*np.arange(-1,1,0.025)
)
```

[image]

### Contour Lines Accumulate at the Negative Imaginary Axis $-i \, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$

```
t = np.arange(-1,1,0.025)
plt.contour(t,t, np.angle(t[...,None] + 1j*t[None,...]) , levels = 2*np.pi*np.arange(-1,1,0.025))

L = 0.25
plt.xlim([-L,L])
plt.ylim([-L,L])
```

[image]

---

### Code Inspection

```
import inspect
print inspect.getsource(plt.contour)

@_autogen_docstring(Axes.contour)
def contour(*args, **kwargs):
    ax = gca()
    # allow callers to override the hold state by passing hold=True|False
    washold = ax.ishold()
    hold = kwargs.pop('hold', None)
    if hold is not None:
        ax.hold(hold)
    try:
        ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
        draw_if_interactive()
    finally:
        ax.hold(washold)
    if ret._A is not None: sci(ret)
    return ret
```

```
print inspect.getsource(plt.Axes.contour)

def contour(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self._hold:
        self.cla()
    kwargs['filled'] = False
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Finally one can call on the function containing the actual source code:

```
import matplotlib
print inspect.getsource(matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet)
```

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/48841158e4eb81fcc79b42747a705cb36920ee1b/lib/matplotlib/contour.py

Comment: [`_contour.h`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/48841158e4eb81fcc79b42747a705cb36920ee1b/src/_contour.h) seems to play a key role - it has some discussions of the algorithm  `plt.contour` seems to be an API call of an API call of an API...